# Retrieve google account in-app billing v3

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, account, accountmanager

How can I retrieve the Google Account used for an in-app billing purchase with In-App Billing v3 API ?

I've searched a bit around AccountManager class, which can lead me to the registered accounts on the device, but if the device contains more than 1 google account this way doesn't seem very accurate!

Any lead would be appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: For those looking for the anwser, I've found no actual way of doing this over few months.